# Get pixel values from an image in C#? Why are they different from values in Matlab?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I write a c# code to get the pixel values from a grayscale image.

```
Color x= c.GetPixel(i,j);
byte y=(byte)(((int)x.R+x.G+x.B)/3);
```

I compared them with the values getting in Matlab with imread command. Why are they completely different? The values are between 0 and 255 in C# and in Matlab.
For example:

- `i=0, j=0` - C#: `153`, Matlab: `149`
- `i=0, j=1` - C#: `153`, Matlab: `152`
- `i=0, j=1` - C#: `170`, Matlab: `156`

Comment: You might also want to demonstrate how you're getting colours in Matlab, and add a Matlab tag.

Comment: Can you provide the individual R,G, and B values at your chosen point, and your Matlab calculation?

Answer (score 2):

Grayscale is **not** just an *average*

```
 Y != (R + G + B) / 3
```

For instance, mix of `R + B` - *purple* - should be *darker* than `R + G` - *yellow*. Correct formula is (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale for details)

```
 Y = (299 * R + 587 * G + 114 * B) / 1000
```

**C# Code**:

```
 byte y = (byte)((499 + 299 * x.R + 587 * x.G + 114 * x.B) / 1000);
```